# how to read body using RestTemplate in case of an error?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-rest

I'm using RestTemplate to communicate with one REST service, i use

```
     restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, MyResponse.class);
 } catch (HttpClientErrorException e)
```

however when there is an error (4xx or 5xx) REST service returns description in JSON in a body, but HttpClientErrorException.getResponseBodyAsString()
returns null. RestTemplate (if i try to retrieve response as String), doesn't return anything as well.

How to retrieve body in case of error?

Comment: how did you create restTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was recognised, it's described here
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16781?focusedCommentId=159473&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-159473
and here
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9367

you need to use different http library, for example Apache HttpClient (not a default one from JDK).

Add to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and configure RestTemplate with:

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

you can use **ResponseErrorHandler** if you need, but it's not necessary.

Now response body (even in error situation) is stored in **HttpClientErrorException**, read it with **getResponseBodyAsString()** method.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the response for errors via a [`ResponseErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResponseErrorHandler.html). The `ResponseErrorHandler` needs to be set for the `RestTemplate` with the [`setErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#setErrorHandler-org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler-) method.

The ResponseErrorHandler provides the response via the two methods

> boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException;
>
> void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException;

Comment: you can access error codes (but the same you can do by reading them from exception), but you can't access response body.